# Canonical map from sheaf of differential operators to tangent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

In his paper *"Tangent spaces in moduli via deformations with applications to Weierstrass points"*, Steven Diaz describes the following construction:

For a smooth projective curve over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and any line bundle $L$ on $C$ there is a short exact sequence of sheaves on $C$

\begin{align*}
0 \to \mathcal{O}_C \to \Sigma_L \to \Omega_{C/k}^\vee \to 0
\end{align*}

where $\Sigma_L$ is the locally free rank $2$ sheaf of differential operators of order at most $1$, so morphisms $D$ of sheaves of groups $L \to L$, s.t. for every function f $\in \mathcal{O}_C$ the commutator $[D,f]$ is a function in $\mathcal{O}_C$.

My question is, what is the second map in this sequence? On the level of open affines this is quite clear, as here $\Sigma_L$ splits, so is generated as $\mathcal{O}_C$-module by $1$ and $d: f \mapsto \frac{d}{dx}f$, so functions are mapped to $0$ and $d \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. However, I think there is a much more conceptual canonical way to think about this construction, so I would be thankful if someone could provide me with a such a description.

Comment: With your notations, the map $f\mapsto [D,f]$ is a derivation, hence given by a vector field. You'll find a much more general study in EGA IV, §16. The question would be better suited for MSE.